# How can I transition between these floors at differing levels?

Tags: trim, plywood, transition

I need some ideas for the transition trim. I don't want it too tall. I have kids and don't want them to trip over it.

[image: Transition between rooms]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram or a picture showing how tall the flooring is on either side relative to the center would really help.

Comment: You say your plywood is too "tall" (I'd use the word "thick", but hey); have you considered buying plywood of a different thickness? If you need the same thickness for both edges, it should be fairly easy. If one of your flooring types has a different thickness of lip to the other, then it becomes a bit more difficult.

Comment: Run a straightedge from the high plane out over the low plane and tell us what the difference is. It's impossible to tell what we're seeing here.

Comment: What flooring is going on either side? Are the two floor coverings of equal thickness?

Answer (score 1):

Usual practice is to bridge the gap with a slightly raised threshold board, sloped on one of both sides, rabbeted underneath to account for the higher floor. I have two such in sight right now.

Comment: Please post a photo for the OP's convenience.

Comment: I believe this is actually a duplicate, and pix (including mine) were posted on the previous instance ... But I haven't tracked it down yet.